# How do I display RSS values with checkboxes for each value in HTML?

Tags: java, html, xslt, checkbox, rss

I have RSS feed and Java project. I want to extract the feed values and list them on web page along with checkbox for each value. I could not do that with XML. Is there a way I can extract the values, add checkboxes and display in HTML?

Do I have to transform using XSLT first in order to do this?

Comment: You can transform the RSS feed(XML) with XSLT to HTML containing the CheckBox'es. This would be quite easy if you'd give us a [mcve].